# Lazy loading of Angular controllers using RequireJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, requirejs

I am new to the Angular world, and currently trying to finalize a clean design for our ASP.NET MVC project whereby each Angular controller is in a separate file.  My question is this, is it possible to lazy load the Angular controllers?  I am currently struggling with RequireJS.  My proof of concept code is as follows:

**CSHTML VIEW - Index.cshtml**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Controllers/mainController.js"></script> 
<div class="row" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <span>{{1+1}}</span>

        Message Test: {{testmessage}}
        <button ng-click="ucase()">Upper</button>
</div>
```

**_Layout.cshtml (first line only to show ng-app)**

```
<html ng-app="mainModule">
```

**app.js**

```
var mainModule = angular.module("mainModule", []);
```

**mainController.js**

```
angular.module('mainModule').controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.testmessage = "hello world!";
    $scope.ucase = function () {
        $scope.testmessage = angular.uppercase($scope.testmessage);
    }
}]);
```

How can I get rid of the reference to mainController.js in the Index.cshtml file?  Is there a way to lazy load the controller when it is needed?  Can RequireJS help with this?

Comment: requirejs can be used and I've used in some old projects. However, these days I prefer to use grunt and combine all js in to a single js file which is included in the html.
This allows separating controllers, services, directives in to separate files and it avoids use of requirejs.

Comment: May be this will help you: http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I was able to implement lazy loading of Angular modules in my POC project by using ocLazyLoader:

https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

http://plnkr.co/edit/aGxuXMiPgYA0TFc67YL4 (demo)

However, I am still not sure whether we will implement this going forward.

Comment: Don't hesitate to take a new look at ocLazyLoad as it has been greatly improved lately :)